# Low res image taking too long to load

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, dispatch-async

Using Facebook Graph API, I retrieved a string URL to a `200x200` profile picture that I want to display in a `UIImageView`. I'm successfully able to do this, but I notice that it can take as long as 10 seconds for the image to display on the screen. Can anyone give me some pointers (no pun intended) on how to optimize it?

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: self.profilePictureUrl)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) ->
        Void in
        self.profilePictureImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.profilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profilePictureImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
        self.profilePictureImageView.clipsToBounds      = true

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.view.addSubview(self.profilePictureImageView)
        })

    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Maybe try adding the subview outside of the async call, then just set the image of the subview in the completion block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move all `UIView` calls (so anything you set on the `UIImageView`)  onto the main thread as UIKit for the most part isn't thread-safe.  You can instantiate the `UIImage` on the background thread though for performance optimization, so try this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let url = NSURL(string: self.profilePictureUrl)!

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(
        url,
        completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) -> Void in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            // create the UIImage on the background thread
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)

            // then jump to the main thread to modify your UIImageView
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [weak self] () -> Void in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                let profilePictureImageView = strongSelf.profilePictureImageView

                profilePictureImageView.image = image
                profilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePictureImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
                profilePictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true

                strongSelf.view.addSubview(profilePictureImageView)
            })
        }
    ).resume()
}
```

Note also that I've `weak`-ified your references to `self`.  There is no guarantee the user hasn't dismissed the view controller that is initiating this code by the time the completion routines get called so you want to make sure you're not keeping a strong reference to `self`.  This allows the view controller to deallocate if the user dismisses it and the completion routines then return early without doing any unnecessary work.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of these improvement. I am curious - did you intentionally create two references to `strongSelf`? I only ask because Xcode gives a warning for one of those declarations.

Comment: Yes, you'll need two references to `strongSelf` because each callback potentially hops a thread.  If Xcode is complaining you'll have to change one of the variable names, so for example make the inner one `strongSelfInner`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is illegal:

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: self.profilePictureUrl)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) ->
    Void in
    self.profilePictureImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Stop! you are setting a UIImageView's image *on a background thread*. No no no. UIKit is not thread-safe. You must get onto the main thread to do this. (You do eventually get onto the main thread in your code, but you are doing it too late.)